# Converting VB.NET Lambda to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, dictionary, lambda

Here is the working VB code where I am selecting the values of a Dictionary to write to a file.

```
Dim csv As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    dmap.Select(Function(d) d.Key & "," & d.Value))

Dim filePath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\myfile.csv"

If File.Exists(filePath) Then
    File.Delete(filePath)
End If
        '
File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv)
```

I tried to convert the Lambda on line 1 to C# and got this far:

```
string csv = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dmap.Select(d => d.Key + "," + d.Value));
```

The problem that is everything from `dmap.Select` to the end is underlined in Red.

Here is what it says:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary does not contain a definition for 'Select' accepting a first argument of type Dictionary could be found.

What is the problem here ?   Many thanks !

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: `What is the problem here ?`  You are supposed to *us* the problem/exception/how actual results are incorrect.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I don't see a problem.  Is this supposed to be a fun guessing game or something?

Comment: dmap.Select (...).ToArray ()

Comment: No, No guessing game.  everything from dmap.Select to the end is underlined in Red.  Here is what it says:  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string> does not contain a definition for 'Select' accepting a first argument of type Dictionary<string, string> could be found.

Comment: It *is* a guessing game when you dont include the error message in the post at the outset.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

According to the error you mentioned in the comments, it says:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary does not contain a definition for 'Select' accepting a first argument of type Dictionary could be found.

This is most likely because you are missing a reference to the Linq libraries, which extend classes that implement `IEnumerable` with [this and other methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

Try adding this to the top of your code file:

```
using System.Linq;
```